# jQuery overwriting function

Tags: jquery

So, first the code:

```
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
    var filled = $("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value.length > 0;
    });
```

Part1

```
if (filled.length < 1) {                        
    var test= $('#test').val();
    if (test == ""){
        $('#test').css('border-color',green);
    }
} else { ... }
```

Part 2

```
if (filled.length > 0 && filled.length <= 4) {                  
    $('#test').keyup(function() {
        var test = $('#test').val();
        if (test=="") {
            $('#test').css('border-color',red);
        }
    }
});
```

This is from a form where there is 4 text inputs that are optional but if user field in one of them he have to field them all.

So when filled.length is >0 and <=4 the fields are required and I want the input border to be red for example.

But when filled.length <1 (=0) then I want all the border to be green.

The problem is that if I write something on the inputs and then erase it all, 
they should tourn green but the Part2 overwrite the Part1 and they show up red.

My question are:
- **How do I fix that?**
- **Where does this problem came from?**(jquery theory)

The closer I could get to a "right" code is replacing part 1 with:

```
if(filled.length < 1)
{                       
     $('#test').keyup(function()
     {
         var test = $('#test').val();

         if(test=="")
         {
              $('#test').css('border-color',green);
         }
     }

}
```

But then when the input is empty, I have to erase one more time (key up), for part 1 to kick in and replace part 2.

PS: If more code is needed or explanation about the problem, please ask =).

**EDIT**
The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WzE9k/13/. Code isn't exactly the same but the point is the same. When the field is empty it should show "nothing is write" but it doesn't.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) when you have that much code :).

Comment: Please format your code before posting a question; it'll greatly increase its chance of being answered.

Comment: I think jsfiddle is needed as well everything looks good I feel like the filter function is the problem. Why not do an each and then call a function and use "this" as reference for checking values.

Comment: Ok ok, I'm doing the jsfiddle.

Comment: Start by quoting the css values `green` and `red`, as they are strings.

Comment: And I'm guessing this is what you are after : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vCvYz/) ...

Comment: @adeneo, ya something close to that indeed =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a sample of what you can do

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    // store how many textboxes are not empty
    var len = $('input').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val().length > 0
    }).length;
    $('input').css('border', function() {
        // if number is less than 4 and greater than zero
        // return red
        // else return green
        return len < 4 && len > 0 ? 'red solid 1px' : 'green solid 1px';
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7mVLu/

Heres a fiddle with the text changing

http://jsfiddle.net/7mVLu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with vanilla JavaScript would work and run much faster with a ton of fields.

http://jsfiddle.net/TzqPT/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access multiple items then i would better suggest to use the `class` so that you can distinguish any other same elements that exist within same parent.

check this
http://jsfiddle.net/GgzC5/